# Updating checkbox each time it is checked or unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a 6 checkboxes checked/unchecked based on values from the database, the 5th checkbox is unchecked, to get the state, I use the snippet below:

```
var allCheckboxes = $(':input[name="cc_checkbox"]').map(function () {
  return this.value;
}).get();
```

when I `console.log(allCheckboxes)` I get `["1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1"]` which is right.

But when I check/uncheck any of the checkboxes and `console.log(allCheckboxes)`, I still get `["1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "1"]`

Is this a normal a behaviour or is there some other syntax I need to use?

Comment: Can you please share your html? What is the value of `value` attributes in your checkboxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the `value` of a checkbox is always present. It doesn't change depending on whether or not the element is checked.

To solve this you could put the `checked` property of the elements in to the array instead:

```js
var allCheckboxes = $(':input[name="cc_checkbox"]').map(function () {
  return this.checked;
}).get();
```

Given the example in your OP this would give you an array output of:

```
[true, true, true, true, false, true]
```